# Combine same column name data of two different tables in sql to a result set including null

Tags: sql, plsql

I have below two tables which i need to combine together into my daily reports.

**Table 1: Resource_Created**

**FirstName        LastName        ObjDate         Resource        Login**

```
TestDemo1        TestDemo1       5-Oct-12         AD         TESTDEMO1
```

**Table 2: Resource_Deleted**

**FirstName       LastName        ObjDate         Resource        Login**

```
TestDemo4        TestDemo4       5-Oct-12         AD         TESTDEMO4

TestDemo5        TestDemo5       5-Oct-12         AD         TESTDEMO5

TestDemo6        TestDemo6       5-Oct-12         AD         TESTDEMO6

TestDemo4        TestDemo4       5-Oct-12         Bio        TESTDEMO4

TestDemo4        TestDemo4       5-Oct-12         VPN        TESTDEMO4

TestDemo5        TestDemo5       5-Oct-12         VPN        TESTDEMO5

TestDemo6        TestDemo6       5-Oct-12         VPN          TESTDEMO6
```

I wrote two queries individually like

Query 1:

```
select distinct Resource as Resource, 
       count (distinct Login) as CountRes 
from Resource_Created 
where ObjDate between '4-Oct-12' and '6-Oct-12' 
group by Resource ;
```

Result:

**Resource CountRes**

```
 AD        1
```

Query 2:

```
select distinct Resource as Resource, 
       count (distinct Login) as CountRes 
from Resource_Deleted 
where ObjDate between '4-Oct-12' and '6-Oct-12' 
group by Resource ;
```

Result

**Resource  CountRes**

```
AD          3

VPN         3

Bio         1
```

I wish to combine these two queries, so that i can have one table display these values.

```
select COALESCE (Resource_Created.Resource, Resource_Deleted.Resource) as Resource , 
 count (distinct Resource_Created.usrlogin) as aobj, 
 count (distinct Resource_Deleted.usrlogin) as bobj
FROM target_failed  FULL OUTER JOIN target_resource  
 on Resource_Created.Resource = Resource_Deleted.Resource 
where
 Resource_Created.ObjDate between '04-OCT-2012' and '06-OCT-2012' and 
 Resource_Deleted.ObjDate between '04-OCT-2012' and '06-OCT-2012'
group by COALESCE(Resource_Created.Resource, Resource_Deleted.Resource);
```

**My Result was**

```
**Resource       aobj         bobj**

   AD         1                3
```

**Expected Result**

**Resource       aobj       bobj**

```
 AD             1          3

VPN           Null         3

Bio           Null         1
```

Please could anyone help me resolve the issue. I am just a OO developer who writes  basic sql queries. It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use sub sql on from statement

```
select 
  ResourceI as rs, sum (CreatedLogin) as CountCreated,
 sum (DeletedLogin) as CountDeleted
from 
(select 
 ObjDate,
 Resource ,
 1 as DeletedLogin,
 0 as CreatedLogin 
 from  Resource_Deleted
 union all
 select ObjDate,
 Resource ,
 0 as DeletedLogin,
 1 as CreatedLogin  
 from  Resource_Created
)  TABLE_ALL
where ObjDate between TO_DATE('4-Oct-12') and TO_DATE('6-Oct-12')
group by Resource
```

Comment: FROM keyword not found where expected. Also I wish the result to look like what i have displayed in my expected result.

Comment: Thank you so much hkutluay. Please could you explain me sum (CreatedLogin) as CountCreated,
 sum (DeletedLogin) as CountDeleted when you have given the column name login.

Comment: @user1744539 i selected dummy columns DeletedLogin, CreatedLogin on from sub query. when records come from resource_deleted table, it returns 1 as deletedlogin and 0 as createdlogin. On resouce_created table vice versa.